# How to calculate this kind of probability for a normal distribution?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

here is my question.
I have a normal distribution with known mean and variance.

Say the mean is 3 and the Var. is 2.

what is the probability that the random variable is taking value 2.9?

If I plug in the value 2.9 into the formula for normal distribution, I think I only get the density value at the point 2.9, not the probability.

I understand for continuous random variable, the prob. at individual point is zero.

In my problem, I just want to know what's the prob. that the random variable is going to take value 2.9?

How can I do it?

Should I calculate the this prob. using a small interval that includes 2.9, for example,
I calculate the probability  when the random variable falls into the interval [2.85, 2.95]? And using this probability as my answer?

Thank you
John

Comment: You have answered the question, the probability is $0$. If you want the probability that the random variable to one decimal place is $2.9$, your $2.85$ to $2.95$ will work.